# I can't interact with Office without first giving it focus

Tags: microsoft-office

On one system I'm using, if an Office application is visible on the screen, but does not have focus, clicking buttons in that application won't interact with the buttons; instead, it gives that application focus. I have to click a second time to trigger the event.

When the app already has focus, everything works ok.
Office on other Systems doesn't have this issue, neither do other MS apps on this system, so I'm thinking it's something from my settings, hut I can't find anything that looks like the solution.

Edit: This is Office 2013 running on a Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit) VM.

Comment: what is that system (OS) and what are the others? any other difference between them?

Comment: Is this Office 2007? I've seen this bug before but never figured out how to fix it :/ maybe a re-install would work. I am 99.678% certain that this is not a "setting".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Office 2013 under Windows 10 (not able to select text with the mouse / the keyboard, randomly, activation of windows (in word) and so on. I was not able to work with word.
I then have removed the (yesterday applied) Windows sercurity update **KB3135175** rebooted my machine and... since then, it works again.

[Link to MS to the problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-crash-when-using-the-mouse-to-select-text/c615de3e-3877-4e02-bb0e-5e0fd9ff5355)